# Get element of parent document from inside of new window that is called from iframe in parent?

Tags: jquery, iframe, window, parent

I have an iframe inside main body of document:

```
<body>

 <span id="x">Hello</span>

 <iframe>

  ... onclick="window.open(url,'myWindow','width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes');"

 </iframe>

</body>
```

from inside of myWindow i want to get "Hello". how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i get your question, but window.open returns a reference to the new window. So you can acces it by

```
var myWindow = window.open(url,'myWindow','width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes');
var text = myWindow.document.body.innerHTML; //or something else..
```

Comment: myWindow.document.write("Hallo")? Or the other way?

Comment: Ah, i think you want access FROM the newly opened page TO the page that opens it? I dont know if thats possible.. (I would say no...) But ofcourse you CAN use querystring parameters to pass arguments... Like `window.open(url+'?vara=hallo','myWindow','width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes');` and then access it from your newly opened windw, by inspecting the querystring (lots of results on google for that)

Comment: i can send "hello" in url when open myWindow. but i try to get it from inside of myWindow, somthing like : document.parent or document.top ...

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. What's against using querystring vars?

Comment: i think it's not pretty to send everything by url. but if it's not possible i try to find other solution. tnx a lot.